# How to remove (not revert) a CL?

Tags: perforce

I want to entirely remove a CL from perforce.  Not revert, but when you look up the "History" of the depot tree, it will be gone.  All changes will be permanently removed.  Is this possible?  I'm using P4V.

Answer (score 5):

The only way to permanently delete file history is to use the [obliterate](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/obliterate.html) command, which requires superuser access. I think that if you obliterated all the file revisions from a changelist, it shouldn't appear anymore.

Use extreme caution when obliterating, as there's no going back once it's done (well, outside of restoring from a backup).